# Embeding Movilizer Client In My Application

Tags: movilizer

I have created a Mobile application in Movilizer. I have three to four movelets in it. Now I want to embed the Movilizer client in my program and deploy it in Google play store so that anyone downloading from there would get the client along with it and can run my application without having to download the client separately.

What is the procedure for the same?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Movilizer is a standalone app which contains many movelets.

If you wanna to create a separate container for your company, you can create the same by using Google cloud developer console platform.

For that you should create a signedAPK and should register in Google developer console.

Note: Initial payment = 25$